# Form Validation not working in custom component Vue

Tags: vue.js

Vue 3.4.21

I have a form and when I add elements to it without using a custom component, validation works:

```
   <div class="form-group element">
          <input type="text" :name="name" class="form-control" placeholder=" "
            required pattern="([\w]{2,})" />
          <label :for='x.slug' class="form-control-placeholder">
            Name: 
          </label>
          <span class="error-msg">Please type at least 2 characters </span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The error message appears as it's supposed to.

Now, I've created a custom component like so:

```
        <template>
            <div class="form-group element">
                <input type="text" :name="name" class="form-control :required='required'>
                <label :for='name' class="form-control-placeholder">
                    {{ name }}:
                </label>
                <span class="error-msg">{{ errorMsg }}</span>
            </div>
        </template>

        <script setup>

        import { toRefs } from 'vue'

        const props = defineProps({
            pattern: String,
            errorMsg: String,
            name: String,
            required: Boolean,
        })
        const { pattern, name, errorMsg, required } = toRefs(props);
        </script>
```

And I use it like this:

```
   <CustomInput
      :errorMsg="'Please write at least 2 characters'" 
      :required="true"
      :name="'name'"
      :pattern="'([\w]{2,})'"
    />
```

The error message appears even when I meet the criteria (typing at least 2 characters)

How do I make validation function correctly when passing in props to a custom component as opposed to hard coding them on the page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of mistakes in the code, and the main thing in the key of the question is that you don't pass the `pattern` to the `input` component. I created a [simple example](https://play.vuejs.org/#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) for you where everything works.

```
// App.vue

<script setup>
import Input from './Input.vue';
</script>

<template>
  <form>
    <Input
      :required="true"
      pattern="([\w]{2,})"
    />
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

```
// Input.vue

<script setup>
defineProps({
  type: String,
  name: String,
  required: Boolean,
  errorMsg: String,
  pattern: String
})
</script>

<template>
  <div class="form-group element">
      <input
        :type="type"
        :name="name"
        :required="required"
        :pattern="pattern"
        class="form-control"
      >
      <label
        :for="name"
        class="form-control-placeholder"
      >
        {{ name }}
      </label>
      <span class="error-msg">{{ errorMsg }}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the only thing I changed was removing the single quotes from the pattern string and removing the ":" from in front of the pattern prop. So 2 changes, not a lot of mistakes :)

Comment: I asked another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78252875/passing-function-as-prop-isnt-firing-parent-method.. maybe you can be my guardian angel today